# How to configure Wysiwyg + Ckeditor Library not to breaks source code lines

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm using WYSIWYG Module with ckeditor as an editor.
I use it with the full_html format

My problem is that when switching from the rich-code to the source code view all the line breaks are removed.

So this portion of code :

```
<div class="highlight">
    <p>Nemo enim <a href="#">ipsam voluptatem quaerat voluptatem.</a></p>
</div>
<div class="body">
    <p><strong>Doloremque laudantium,</strong> totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

transforms into something like this :

```
<div class="highlight"><p>Nemo enim <a href="#">ipsam voluptatem quaerat voluptatem.</a></p></div><div class="body"><p><strong>Doloremque laudantium,</strong> totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p></div>
```

Is there a configuration that prevents this from happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [WYSIWYG Linebreaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_linebreaks).

Comment: Thank you ! Exactly what i needed.
If someone needs this, you need to install the WYSIWYG Linebreaks module then enable **Force Linebreaks** in the Buttons & Plugins at : 
 **admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/full_html**